# Conditionally display a ModalPopupExtender AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I know you can utilize a `ModalPopupExtender` and have it be displayed when the user clicks a button or something of the sort by assigning the `TargetControlID`. What I'm looking to do is display this popup when an error occurs on my page. So by using conditional logic in the `C#` side of things, for example, if a certain variable is set to something, display this popup.
Is there a way I can do this, or something similar?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185226/modalpopupextender-how-to-show-only-when-certain-conditions-are-met

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, in your C# code you can call

```
my_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
```

Where `my_ModalPopupExtender` is the name of your popup extender.

It's that easy!

Comment: Thanks! I wondered if it had a Show/Hide attribute! Easy as pie!

Answer (score 0):

If, loading page, you know condition to show or not popup you can remove or not ModalPopupExtender!
In my case, populating a table using repeater :

```
 protected void Repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

        ModalPopupExtender ModalPopupExtenderLinkButton =
          e.Item.FindControl("ModalPopupExtenderLinkButton") as ModalPopupExtender;

        if (condition)
          e.Item.Controls.Remove(ModalPopupExtenderLinkButton);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help!